# Dúvida sobre a utilização do `for` em sistema de votação

Tags: c, string, matriz, array

Eu quero fazer um programa onde o usuário dá o número de candidatos e seus nomes, e então a votação é iniciada até que o usuário digite fim. Ajuda?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char nome[30][30];
    char vot[30];
    int ponto[30];
    int n,i,j,k,maior=0,aux;
    char fim[] = "fim";

    scanf("%i", &n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        gets(nome[i]);
    }

    printf("A votacao comecou\n");


    for(i=0;i<=30;i++)
    {
        ponto[i]=0;
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        gets(vot);
        k=strcmp(vot,fim);
        if(k==0)
        {
            printf("A votacao terminou\n");
            break;
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            j=stricmp(vot,nome[i]);
            if(j==0)
            {
                ponto[i]=ponto[i]+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if (ponto[i]>maior) aux=i;
    }

    printf("O vencedor e:\n");
    puts(nome[aux]);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Depois de definir `ponto` como um array com 30 elementos, o último elemento do array é `ponto[29]`; o elemento `ponto[30]` não existe.

Answer (score 2):

No último ciclo

```
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if (ponto[i]>maior) aux=i;
    }
```

a variável `maior` não muda de valor. Começou a `0` e continua `0` no fim do ciclo.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo... funcionou direitinho... Quando vi o que estava errado não acreditei kkkkkk.